In AEM 6.5, IMS configuration Oauth showing unhealthy configuration but same config working on local instance
In AEM 6.5 onPrime I have a AEM brand portal setting which i converted from JWT To Oauth. When i check the health of my IMS Configuration,  its showing unhealthy configuration hostname may not be empty.
The same Oauth setting is working in my local instance.
what configuration i might be missing on server?
I have created the IMS configuration with Oauth option and provided all required values from developer console project auth.
I also tested the Oauth in Postman and its generating the access token
